# Rename files that have consecutive numbers for extensions

Tags: linux, file, rename, bulk

I have a directory with a few hundred files in the following format:

```
file.txt.1
file.txt.2
file.txt.3
file.txt.4
...
```

I need to rename these all to this format:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
...
```

Comment: Very good - what have you tried? :)

Comment: lol, i have no idea where to start. basically i'm at: mv file.txt.1 file1.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do what you're asking but it will rename all the files the way you need. Just save it to a file (`rename.sh` for example) then give it execution permissions (`chmod +x rename.sh`) and run with `./rename.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
for filename in file*; do 
    newFile=`echo $(basename $filename) | awk -F'.' '{print $1 $3 "." $2}'`
    echo mv \"$filename\" \"$(dirname $filename)/$newFile\";
done | /bin/bash
```

If you wanted to run a dry-run, replace `| /bin/bash` with `> renames.txt`. This will save all the renamed files to the text file where you can review the changes.

Comment: not sure if it's the best way either ... but it worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mmv`, install `sudo apt-get install mmv`.

```
$ mmv -n '*.*.*' '#1.#3.#2'
file.txt.1 -> file.1.txt
file.txt.2 -> file.2.txt
file.txt.3 -> file.3.txt
```

---

Or use `find` and [shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) parameter substitution expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
find . -type f -execdir sh -c 'num=${1##*.}; echo mv -v "$1" "file.${num}.txt" ' _ {} \;
```

- Remove `echo` to perform actual rename on files.